# InvalidEntrypoint for AWS Lambda with python docker container

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I've built an image for Lambda using `public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8` but always get this error.

Tried changing up the function and file names, but not getting any more details for debugging.

Also I've run the function locally and the entrypoint/cmd works.

```
START RequestId: cb4ba88c-c347-4e7d-b1ca-031a2e02fde4 Version: $LATEST
IMAGE   Launch error: fork/exec /lambda-entrypoint.sh: exec format error    Entrypoint: [/lambda-entrypoint.sh] Cmd: [index.lambda_handler] WorkingDir: [/var/task]IMAGE    Launch error: fork/exec /lambda-entrypoint.sh: exec format error    Entrypoint: [/lambda-entrypoint.sh] Cmd: [index.lambda_handler] WorkingDir: [/var/task]END RequestId: cb4ba88c-c347-4e7d-b1ca-031a2e02fde4
REPORT RequestId: cb4ba88c-c347-4e7d-b1ca-031a2e02fde4  Duration: 12.86 ms  Billed Duration: 13 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 3 MB   
RequestId: cb4ba88c-c347-4e7d-b1ca-031a2e02fde4 Error: fork/exec /lambda-entrypoint.sh: exec format error
Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Turned out to be an architecture compatibility issue -

Needed to make sure the arch matched between the lambda function, and the docker image.

Locally I was building on an M1 with `arm64` but the function is configured by default to use `amd64`

I changed my build command to
`docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t <image_name>:<image_tag>`

Although I could have also updated the arch type for the lambda function to use `arm64`

Comment: Had the same issue. If using an M1 mac, will need to set the lambda to arm64

Answer (score 4):

For those weary travellers using Serverless framework and experiencing similar issues...

I had the same for nodejs and docker on Mac M1 using the standard `aws-nodejs-docker-demo`.

To Jeremy's point above, yes you can also simply add `architecture: arm64` to serverless.yml to change the lambda architecture. Arm should be sightly cheaper too.

```
provider:
  name: aws
  region: ap-southeast-2
  architecture: arm64
  ecr:
uploaded to ECR
    images:
      appimage:
        path: ./
```

You should then see the function version switch architecture from x86_64 to arm64

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As Jeremy said, this is an architecture issue. If you are using Serverless Framework on an M1 machine, you can solve that by specifying the `platform` option for the docker image:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  ecr:
    images:
      image_name:
        platform: linux/amd64
```

Further reading about this option can be found [here](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions#referencing-container-image-as-a-target).