Getting Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint Error when using python container with AWS Lambda
I am trying to use the public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10 base image to be used with aws lambda, i am trying to add gossamer3 as a tool in the image and adding some python modules to the image. Here is the error i am seeing
{
"errorType": "Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint",
"errorMessage": "RequestId: 316e57e3-5213-4790-8f97-1bb2563efb77 Error: fork/exec /tmp: permission denied"
}
i have tried setting /tmp and /project as the Workdir in my Dockerfile. I have tired setting chmod 777 on /project exclusively as well(tmp already has open perms). I have tried using the lambda function overrides for ENTRYPOINT,CMD and Workdir as well to point to /tmp but i cant seem to get passed this error.
Has anyone seen this issue?

DId you check the compatibility? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71373337/invalidentrypoint-for-aws-lambda-with-python-docker-container)
check the platform/architecture type of the lambda

I was actually able to fix the issue by setting the WORKDIR to /var/task in my Dockerfile in the beginning. Using Lambda overrides was actually throwing the permission denied error. Thanks
